# Is there a way around cookie and privacy popus in selenium browser?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to make a python script using selenium and bs4 to automatically buy shoes for from adidas.com. It's just that whenever selenium browser starts the adidas site it shows a popup concerning cookies and privacy. I can't click on the accept button using selenium(can't find the element to click on) and I've tried starting the selenium browser with my firefox profile containing cookies and what not. But it still shows that damn popup and it's stopping the script.
Is there anyway to fix this?

Tried starting selenium with firefox cookies like this:

```
ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\chico\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\e5108gza.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ffprofile)
driver.get('https://www.adidas.nl/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-NL-Site/nl_NL/MyAccount-CreateOrLogin')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='dwfrm_login_username']").send_keys('email')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='dwfrm_login_password']").send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@value='Inloggen']").click()
```

The popup from the adidas site just keeps poping up and stopping my script from continuing. Sometimes it will fill in email and password before being stopped, sometimes it will be stopped before that.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue recently, and it was **SO** frustrating, because it can't be handled with a ***"switch to alert"*** and ***"accept"*** it approach sometimes.

Here's how I got around my issue. First, and this was most important, you need to "inspect" the page you are writing selenium code for in a way that the cookie acceptance popup will show up.

For me, I was using the Chrome driver, and so for inspecting the page, I had to run incognito, so that the page would not know I had already accepted cookies. Use the method for Firefox that will achieve the same effect.

Then you can find the element ID (or class name) for the acceptance button and add a click to the end of your command. My code to do this looks as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = "http:some_site.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id(the_id_name_for_cookie_acceptance_as_a_string).click()

# Do more stuff ...
```

Now, if you run into a cookie dialog that won't act as an alert, you can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you posted and didn't receive any alert pop up.But if there is a Alert windows it needs to be handled by switching to it and accepting it

```
 from selenium import webdriver

 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
 driver.get('https://www.adidas.nl/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-NL-Site/nl_NL/MyAccount-CreateOrLogin')


 try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),'Timed out waiting for alert popup')
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
 except:
    print "no alert"



driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='dwfrm_login_username']").send_keys('email')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='dwfrm_login_password']").send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@value='Inloggen']").click()
```

Comment: Tried your solution but it just prints no allert. I'm thinking this is a javascript based pop up or something. Anyways I've made a screenshot of the popup: https://imgur.com/a/b4Ujisv

Comment: From the screenshots, its not showing accept button. you can try fetching the page source at the point of failure and look for the popup dialog code (or) you can try the scenario in incognito mode to check if the popup shows